# Selenium c# with Mailinator

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, mailinator

I am trying to write automated test for a registering process and I send out a html formatted activation email to a mailinator.

In the email there is a button I want to select that takes the user to another page.

I tried selecting the button with almost every way by using xpath, css selector and so on...

Is there any way to make this work? Or any other clients? I would like to try and avoid setting up dummy accounts.

Comment: I just get the href associated with the button from the email and navigate that way.

Comment: And how do you get the href from the e-mail with selenium? Because some part of the link is randomly generated. I just said I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Wait, are you using the Mailinator UI to read the email? If so it's easier to use gmail and imap to get the email into an object you can use and parse with C# - no UI. That's what I'm doing. I have the email body as a string. Before and after the dynamically generated url in the body I know what the text will be so I'm able to parse the string to get the url. This is what I use: https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap